# PowerApp DataCardValue.Text Returning as blank when not blank

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

[image]

I am have a Form in PowerApp which is created using **Edit Form** component. The Datacard has text called TEST but for some reason, this is returning as `Blank`.

I want the button to only be clickable when all of the data card values contain text otherwise it is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to do the following two steps:

1. Set the form mode - Whenever you work with the **Edit Form** component you need to specify in which mode you are going to work. Since you want to add a new record to the list, you need to set the **Form Mode** as `NewForm`. You can set `OnVisible` property of the current screen or `OnSelect` property of the button (if you are navigating from any other screen) as `NewForm(Form1)`. You can find more ways to do so and more insight over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-form).
2. To enable or disable the button as per your requirement, set the `DisplayMode` property of the button as:

```
If( 
    Or( 
       IsBlank(Field1.Text), 
       IsBlank(Field2.Text),
       IsBlank(Field3.Text), 
       IsBlank(Field4.Text)
      ),
    DisaplayMode.Disabled,
    DisaplayMode.Edit
)
```