Power pages multistep form stopped showing/displaying for users after deleting records from table
I have a multistep form on power pages, but after I deleted all records from the table the form is using, the form is no longer showing/displaying on the page. I would appreciate any assistance on how to resolve this.

Hey @JPeter, see if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78062584/powerapp-datacardvalue-text-returning-as-blank-when-not-blank/78063515#78063515

When a user starts a multistep form on the portal, a session record is created for progress tracking. You can find the session record associated with the multistep form in your portal management app - look for the contact linked to the logged-in user.
You'll have to delete the session as well - you may have to navigate into the record and delete it.

